# NUM, does it go on forever?

Tags: candy-box-2

For Candy box two, after throwing away 3,000 pieces of candy does it just KEEP saying "NUM"? Cause if it does, would it be wasting your candies?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a chocolate bar from this quest, you can't get anything else.

So  Yes, after throwing 3000 candies he will just keep saying num, living a peaceful life only eating candies.

Side note : instead of wasting them, you can eat candies, which will boost up your health up to 1 000 when you have eaten a total of 3 000 000 candies.